# Switch statement using string.contains

Tags: c#, string, switch-statement

I have the following method

```
public List<AvailableFile> GetAvailableFiles(string rootFolder)
{

     if (Directory.Exists(rootFolder))
     {

         try
         {
             foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(rootFolder))
             {
                if (f.ToString().Contains("test"))
                {

                     files = CreateFileList(f);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
           // log stuff
        }
   }
   return files;
}
```

What I'm wanting to do is refactor out the if statement inside the foreach loop, making using of a switch statement as I need to check against a variety of different words

However, I'm struggling to put the switch statement in due to use `.Contains()` and for the fact I need to check each of my file names that may or may not have a particular set of characters I'm looking for.

Is there a way in which I can make use of the switch statement or am I stuck with using a variety of if statements?

Edit
Maybe I was unclear in what I was wanting to do. And it would seem how to go about this is very opinion based. Below, is a quick mock up of how I'm picturing this

```
public List<AvailableFile> GetAvailableFiles(string rootFolder)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(rootFolder))
    {
        Log.Info("Checking folder: " + rootFolder + " for files");
        try
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(rootFolder))
            {
                // the if statement is now removed into another method CreateFileList
                files = CreateFileList(f);                 
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
            Log.Fatal("GetAvailableFiles failed: " + excpt.Message);
        }
    }
    return files;
}


// mock up 
private static List<AvailableFile> CreateFileList(string entity)
{
    List<AvailableFile> fileList = new List<AvailableFile>();

    // how I can do it
    if(entity.Contains("test"))
    {
        run process 1
    }
    else if (entity.Contains("run"))
    {
        run process 2
    }

    // the way I'd prefer to have it
    switch(entity)
    {
        case "test":
            run process 1
        break;
        case "run":
            run process 2
        break;
    }

    return fileList;
}
```

If I need to use multiple if statements, I shall, but I'd prefer to use a switch. Is what I'm trying to do currently possible with C#?

Comment: You can create a `IEnumerable<string>` of search terms and loop over it, rather than resorting to individual `if` blocks.

Comment: Switch only does equals comparison

Comment: @Servy as it was my first pass on the method. Currently in the process of re-writing it. Also, not really on topic..

Comment: Your code doesnt even compile. Where is the `files` variable declared? You should also at least break the `foreach` if you have found what you were looking for.

Comment: But i guess you also don't want to search `test` in the complete path to the file but only in it's file-name. Then don't use `string.Contains` but `IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).Contains`(or even `==`).

Comment: @TimSchmelter my code does compile, as stated in my question I was wanting to move the if statement inside of the foreach loop to its own method so I can use a switch statement on it. That is all.

Comment: @N0xus: if it compiles you have a field `files`. Then it's just bad practise because a method `GetAvailableFiles` should not modify the state of an object.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch(entity)
{
    case "test":
```

Only does an equal comparison

You will need to use

```
else if (entity.Contains("run"))
```

You might be able to create a method that returns a function

Answer (score 2):

```
        if (Directory.Exists(rootFolder))
        {
            try
            {
                string[] valid = { "Test", "OtherTest" };

                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(rootFolder))
                {
                    if (valid.Any(v => f.ToString().Contains(v)))
                    {
                        // create file
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // log stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

If you add all your valid strings into the array the linq part "valid.Any(v => f.ToString().Contains(v)" will just check if your f.ToString() is equal to any of these rather than having to create multiple if statements

Comment: please add a short explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(rootFolder).Where(o => o.Contains("test")))
{
    // Code referencing 'f' here
}
```

No need for the separate condition if you're only wanting to iterate over the filenames that *do* contain `"test"`.

Also, as an aside, the call to `ToString` is superfluous, it's already a string I believe.

### EDIT:

This question appears to have changed significantly. I'll leave my answer but it's now probably out of date.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to loop through a list you already have, and check to see if the given string is part of an exising word in that list.

```
using System.Linq;

public List<AvailableFile> GetAvailableFiles(string rootFolder, List<string> wordsToCompare)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(rootFolder))
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(rootFolder))
            {
                if (wordsToCompare.Any(v => f.ToString().Contains(v)))
                {
                    // create file
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        // log stuff
        }
    }
    return files;
}
```